# FineUploader with S3 how to specify object name on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

Where do I specify the format or pattern for the server name that FineUploader creates when uploading to Amazon S3?  I need to have greater control over how the file name and path is created on S3.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`objectProperties.key`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-s3.html#objectproperties-option) option.

You can provide a `String` value or a function that returns the intended key as a `String`.

The following example demonstrates setting a key and performing a blocking action (`$.post`). It uses the jQuery plugin,

```js
// <snip>
objectProperties: {
        key: function(fileId) {
            var keyRetrieval = new qq.Promise(),
                filename = $("#fineUploader").fineUploader("getName", fileId);

            $.post("createKey.html", {name: filename})
                .done(function(data) { keyRetrieval.success(data.key); })
                .fail(function() { keyRetrieval.failure(); });

            return keyRetrieval;
        }
    },
// </snip>
```

A simpler example,

```js
objectProperties: {
        key: function(fileId) {
            var filename = $("#fineUploader").fineUploader("getName", fileId);
            return fileId + "/" + filename;
        }
    },
```

Keep in mind that you should make these keys *unique* if you want to prevent users from overwriting each others' files! Putting each upload in a folder with a random key would prevent this.

Comment: The examples above would be to change the key from the client side script correct?  I would be concerned about someone being able to hack that and send any key they want to the signing code.  Is there a way for the PHP on the server to specify the key, and have the rest of the operation use the key specified by the server?

Comment: No, there isn't any way to do that.  If you are concerned about this sort of thing, you can easily inspect the key name in the policy document or request headers on your signature server and reject them if something looks fishy.

Comment: Well I could at the very least perform a an AJAX request to the server from within the code shown above?  Return the server specified key, then when it is submitted back, check to confirm it was the key specified by the server.  At least in that way, there is no mechanism in place in which the client machine is ever choosing the object name, short of the suffix that includes the file name.  Would something like that work, or is there a problem I an not seeing?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly do that.  If you do perform an asynchronous operation in your key-determination function, your function must adhere to the "promise contract".  That is, it must return a `qq.Promise` instance, which is Fine Uploader's implementation of this pattern.  When the response from your server with the key name comes in, you must call the `success` method on the `qq.Promise` instance you have returned, passing in the key name.  Returning a promise signals to Fine Uploader that work still needs to be done, even though the function returned immediately.  See http://goo.gl/ufhqIp.