# How to handle Plus(+) symbol in s3 object name?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel, java-11

I am new to camel route and stuck with a use case, where I have to upload files to s3 which will contain plus symbol(+) in its name and we have no control over that.  I tried googling to solve this issue but I didn't find any solution, what I found is I have to encode my s3 url which will handle plus(+) symbol but couldn't get how?
also gone through some solutions like [FineUploader with S3 how to specify object name on S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335791/fineuploader-with-s3-how-to-specify-object-name-on-s3) , https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1946, [AWS: how to fix S3 event replacing space with '+' sign in object key names in json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779042/aws-how-to-fix-s3-event-replacing-space-with-sign-in-object-key-names-in-js) but I didn't find a hint from all these.

Here is the example-

```
from("ftp-file-location").toD("S3-location/file+name.xml")
```

The thing is if I use it in same way then I get exception as below

```
2020-08-28 22:59:27.943  WARN 14268 --- [sVpiIngestRoute] o.a.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer    : Error processing exchange. Exchange[]. Caused by: [com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: C4CE2CAE8988D1C0; S3 Extended Request ID: aLzhh+0HZDCYjQrask2AqkwvaIckpAwj1ZXW1QCOZNPb02QJA9pruje+6BhgwJDATizyZqDYbvA=)]

com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: C4CE2CAE8988D1C0; S3 Extended Request ID: aLzhh+0HZDCYjQrask2AqkwvaIckpAwj1ZXW1QCOZNPb02QJA9pruje+6BhgwJDATizyZqDYbvA=)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1640)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1304)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1058)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4365)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4312)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1755)
    at org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Producer.processSingleOp(S3Producer.java:281)
    at org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Producer.process(S3Producer.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.lambda$process$0(SendDynamicProcessor.java:166)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(DefaultProducerCache.java:298)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:151)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryState.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:476)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:185)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:228)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.sendToConsumers(SedaConsumer.java:266)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.doRun(SedaConsumer.java:180)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.run(SedaConsumer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

But it works fine if I remove the plus(+) symbol from my file name.

Could you please help me on this???
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html#HowdoIconfigureendpoints-Configuringparametervaluesusingrawvalues

Comment: Hi @SneharghyaPathak, this is about how to configure endpoints, my query is about handling special character in endpoint, thanks

Comment: Yes. Is should have been explicit in my comment. The link describes how to handle special characters in the endpoint using the RAW syntax.

Comment: Well its not working out